# Sinus equation with second mystery solution

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to solve the following equation:

$$12 \times \sin(\frac \pi4t - \frac \pi5) + 20 = 30$$

where $0 \leq t \leq 8$.

I got this far:

$$ t=\frac{{\sin^-}^1 (\frac 5 6) + (\frac \pi 5) + n \times 2\pi}{\frac \pi 4} $$

I do get $t\approx 2,1$, but the solutions say I should also get $t\approx 3,5$.

I cannot for the life of me figure out how?

Comment: Is it really $$12\sin\left(\frac{\pi t}4\frac\pi5\right)=10\;?$$ Somehow I doubt it...

Comment: The obvious solution is $\frac{20}{\pi^2}\sin^{-1}\frac{5}{6}=1.99625$. The other solution in the allowed range is $\frac{20}{\pi^2}(\pi-\sin^{-1}\frac{5}{6})=4.36995$

Comment: So either the answer book is wrong or you have a typo in the question.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in the first equation. 
I've corrected it.

Comment: With $x\in [-1,1]$ and $\sin^{-1}x\in [-\pi/ 2,\pi /2]$ the solutions of $\sin y= x$ are $\{k \pi +(-1)^k\sin^{-1} x: k\in Z\}.$

Answer (score 1):

$$12\sin\left(\frac{\pi t}{4}-\frac{\pi}{5}\right)+20=30\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$20-12\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{5}-\frac{\pi t}{4}\right)=30\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$-12\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{5}-\frac{\pi t}{4}\right)=10\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{5}-\frac{\pi t}{4}\right)=-\frac{5}{6}$$

Now, when we take the inverse sine of both sides we got two options, with $n_1\space\wedge\space n_2\in\mathbb{Z}$:

- $$\frac{\pi}{5}-\frac{\pi t}{4}=\pi+\arcsin\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)+2\pi n_1\Longleftrightarrow t=-\frac{16}{5}-\frac{4\arcsin\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)}{\pi}-8n_1$$
- $$\frac{\pi}{5}-\frac{\pi t}{4}=2\pi n_2-\arcsin\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)\Longleftrightarrow t=\frac{4}{5}+\frac{4\arcsin\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)}{\pi}-8n_2$$

Answer (score 0):

$arcsin(sin(\pi /4 *t-\pi/5))=arcsin(5/6)$, for $- \pi /2 \leq \pi /4 *t-\pi/5 \leq \pi /2$

So for $t \approx 2.1, ~ \pi /4 *t-\pi/5 = \pi /4 * 2.1 -\pi/5 \in [\pi/2;~ \pi/2]$

But if you want to find all solutions, you have to substract $ 2 \pi $, so you get $arcsin(sin(\pi /4 *t-\pi/5 -2 \pi))=arcsin(5/6)$, for $- \pi /2 \leq \pi /4 *t-\pi/5 \leq \pi /2$, for $- \pi /2 \leq \pi /4 *t-\pi/5 - 2 \pi \leq \pi /2$

So for $t \approx 3.6, ~ \pi /4 *t-\pi/5 = \pi /4 * 3.6 -\pi/5 - 2 \pi\in [\pi/2;~ \pi/2]$